# How to add and remove items from a list of objects in android?

Tags: android

I have a list of service endpoints in my app which will be showed with a spinner. Now I want to enable that a user can add and remove some of the entries. Is there a easy way to add such a functionality? I added a plus and minus button in my view and now was looking for a way to solve this. Is there already a view with which this can be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usisally you provide list/spinner items via adapter. So when user removes something from list, 
adapter shall take care that this entry dissapears (  do not provide it while providing view, 
adjust totalamount of entries )   and signal to list/spinner that data has changed  ( by calling superclass method *notifyDatasetChanged()* )